# Separate entitlements for iPad and Catalyst

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, mac-catalyst, entitlements

I have a drawing app initially created for iPad. One of the features is a utility that uses core Bluetooth to help locate a misplaced Apple Pencil. This works on iPad but doesn't work on Catalyst since the pencil is paired with an iPad, not a Mac. The Mac version of my app was rejected because the entitlements listed Bluetooth. I've just resubmitted with that entitlement deleted, but I found no way to have it set for just iPad. Is there a way to do that? Or will I have to toggle the setting each time I alternate between iPad and Catalyst builds?

Answer (score 3):

There might be other ways to achieve this but one way comes to mind goes like this:

1. Duplicate the existing entitlement file. Then remove the Bluetooth capability from this duplicate. Let's name this entitlement file myAppName-mac.entitlements.
2. Go to Project settings of your app and then create another release configuration - let's call this new configuration Release-mac. Make this new configuration based on your current Release configuration.
3. Now select your app target > Build Settings. In build settings, find the entry with the name "Code Signing Entitlements". You can now associate different entitlements with different release configurations. Go ahead and associate "myAppName-mac.entitlements" with your "Release-mac" configuration.
4. Create a new scheme - let's name it myApp-mac. Select this scheme and edit it.

[image: showing how to create a scheme in XCode]

5. You can associate this scheme with the new release configuration you created in Step 2. Do this for Run, Test, Profile, Analyze and Archive build variants.

[image: showing how to associate scheme with a release configuration]

6. Now when you are ready to publish your app, select the appropriate scheme before running the archive job.

Comment: I like this solution. I will try it this weekend, and if it works as expected, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I think run, test, and analyze can stay as debug.

Comment: yes, archive job is the crucial one. The rest can be anything else.

Comment: Solid approach, we had some entries in the entitlements file that were causing the exact same issue and sometimes even a rejection from App Review team. This solution solves our problem. Thanks!